# I want to center the text in the last column, but I don't know how

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

So I have this section of code, out of a larger table, but the text in the last column isn't in the center (verticaly), and also not in the same distance horizontaly like the the other cells. I don't know how to fix it.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
    \newcolumntype{k}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{o}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
        \begin{tabular}{|k{.25\textwidth}|o{.25\textwidth}|o{.124\textwidth}|o{.245\textwidth}|}
            \multirow{2}{=}{Privatübergäng ohne öffentlichen Verkehr}& bei \(v_E >\)\,\,140km/h:\linebreak tS &\multicolumn{2}{o{.42\textwidth}|}{\multirow{2}{=}{Ü \linebreak oder P + Lf (60km/h)\linebreak oder A + Sprechanlage \linebreak oder A}}\\
            \cline{2-2}
            &bei \(v_E\le\)\,\,140km/h:\linebreak Ü + A\linebreak oder A + Sprechanlage & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}\\
        \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Do you want to center the contents of the last column horizontally or vertically? Proabably adding a sketch of the expected output would help clarify?

Comment: In your current code, you declare a total of 4 columns and later on merge two of them using `\multicolumn`. Will you need all 4 columns later in your table (I assume, this is just an excerpt of a larger table.)?

Comment: Simply add `\centering`  at the beginning of the last `\multirow`.

Comment: Next time, please give a working example. I had to remove `\begin{threeparttable}` to get it working. Always compile your examples before putting it here.

Comment: What exactly does "not in the same distance horizontaly like the the other cells" mean? What kind of output do you expect insted of the one you currently get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\multirow` doesn't know about the height of other cells, so if there are cells, like in your example, that are multiline, you should give `\multirow` the number of lines to cover, rather than the number of cells. Sometimes you have to experiment a bit to get the proper value. You can also use fractional numbers for fine-tuning if necessary.

In this case, using `\multirow{4}` instead of `\multirow{2}` seems to give the proper result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you really need 4 columns in your table, you may also be interested in the following `nicematrix`-based appraoch, wich at the same time makes sure, the table is exactly as wide as the textwidth:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\kmh}{\km\per\hour}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\begin{document}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 3pt}
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{0.25\linewidth}
                    p{0.25\linewidth}
                    p{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth}
                    p{0.25\linewidth}}[hvlines]
  \Block[l]{2-1}{Privatübergäng ohne\\ öffentlichen Verkehr}
  & bei \(v_E > \qty{140}{\kmh}\):\newline tS 
  & \Block[l]{2-2}{Ü \\ oder P + Lf (\qty{60}{\kmh})\\ oder A + Sprechanlage \\ oder A} &\\
  & bei \(v_E\le \qty{140}{\kmh}\):\newline Ü + A\newline oder A + Sprechanlage & \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```